# Slow Request/Response - Google OCR API using App Inventor

Tags: google-apps-script, ocr, app-inventor

I am coding an app using App Inventor, the objective of the app is to OCR some image taken from camera/ selected from gallery, and display the ocr content.

i used base64 encoding to transform the image to string, send to google drive by google script, conduct ocr by google script and return the result back to my app.

it worked but for each image (150-1000kB), it take around 7-10 sec to process, as i would like to ocr over 100 images on site operation, the processing time is just too long for practical use.

the following are my App Inventor Block

[Base64 Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNjID.png)

[Add Picture from Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kh3H.png)

[Send request to Google Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9r4m.png)

[Display result from Google Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RFoD.png)

the following are the google script

````
function doPost(e) {
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.data);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.parameters.mimetype, e.parameters.filename);
//provide here a folder ID for the creation of the image file
  var fileID = DriveApp.getFolderById('<Folder ID>').createFile(blob).getId();
  
  if ( fileID !== "" ) {
  try {
// Fetch the image from drive
      var imageBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob();
      var resource = { title: e.parameters.filename, mimeType: imageBlob.getContentType() };
// OCR on .jpg, .png, .gif, (or .pdf uploads)
      var options = { ocr: true };
      var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, imageBlob, options);
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.id);
// Extract the text body of the Google Document
      var text = doc.getBody().getText().replace("\n", "");
// Send the documents to trash
      Drive.Files.remove(docFile.id);
      Drive.Files.remove(fileID);
      status = text;
    } catch (error) {
      status = "ERROR with OCR: " + error.toString();
    }
  } else {
    status = "ERROR with OCR: No image specified";
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(status);
}```
````

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Show what you tried to optimize you app and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: you might want to try another solution from the FAQ here https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/faq-section-optical-character-recognition-ocr/1729 and let me suggest you to ask questions like this in the MIT App Inventor community https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/

Comment: Thanks for using my blocks and script :) https://ai2.metricrat.co.uk/guides/ocr-images-and-pdfs-using-google-docs  The delay in returning the text from an OCR'd image is all happening on Google Drive. The demo is set up to handle images one at a time. What you might do is upload all your images to a folder, then call a google apps script that OCR's each image in turn, saving the text to a file. Then return the texts once all files are OCR'd.

Comment: @Taifun i have searched FAQ you mentioned, the OCR extension for mika worked relatively faster, but the accuracy is not high enough, a sample of the image that need to be OCR is shown below. . I will repost this question in App inventor community again.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jucgc.jpg

Also i would like to credit you both in my app, what is the common way to do so?

Comment: @MetricRat your suggestion (parallel OCR) is quite enlightening,  i will further research on this line of thought, but since i am new in app inventor and google script, any good reference i could look for? 
Also i would like to credit you both in my app, what is the common way to do so?

Comment: @Gilbert well it won't be parallel OCR, more like block OCR. Whether my suggestion is of any use will depend on your workflow, if you need the OCR'd text immediately or if you can collect the OCR'd items at a later time, also whether the google apps script can complete before timing out. As suggested ask on the community.